# Requiring specifying an instance when running a setup.exe from InstallShield

Tags: installshield, multiple-instances

I develop/maintain an installer built with InstallShield that supports multiple instances.  Due to various reasons we always recommend those who run our installer to use the /Instance switch that InstallShield's setup.exe bootstrapper has.  Is it possible to get InstallShield to require that the /Instance switch is used? Or is there anyway to check if the setup.exe has been run without the /Instance switch?

Answer (score 0):

If this is an Install Script installer, you can check the value of the command line parameter when the installer first starts.  If the value of the command line parameter is not what you want, you can display a messagebox to the user and exit.

szCommandLine = CMDLINE;

if (szMasterCommandLine == "/instance") then
        MessageBox("Hello! This installer is running in instance mode.", INFORMATION);
else
MessageBox("You must run this installer with the /instance command line parameter.", INFORMATION);
abort;
endif;